# Region Not Provided Error on attempted write to SQS from ECS

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

I have a container with a python sript that read continuosly data from a RDS Database every amount of time. Every read could send some data to a SQS queue.

```
import boto3

queue=boto3.resource('sqs')

response = queue.send_message(
            MessageBody={"test":"test"}
)
```

When I run the script locally the `boto3` read my local aws configuration and everything works fine but when I deploy to my ecs cluster I get "You must specify a region" Error and `queue` value is `Null`

I have tryed hardcoding Access Key, Secret Key and region. With that works fine, but I don't want to harcode the configuration inside the source code.

There is a way to use credentials provided by ecs like on an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a [Task IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) to the ECS task. This role will be made available to the software running inside the Task's containers, and the AWS SDK that you are using will pick it up and use it automatically.

Note that this is different from the [Task Execution Role](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html), which you had to define in order to allow ECS to deploy your task.

If you still get an error regarding the region after that, you might need to define an `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable in the task definition.

Comment: Setting `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` works. Probably I need to set something in the IAM Role for the region ?

Comment: No, the IAM role gives permission across all regions. The specific region you want to use is an entirely separate setting that you need to pass to the AWS SDK. In my experience, the SDK running on EC2 or ECS will detect the region it is currently running in, and use that as the default region, so I'm not sure why that isn't happening for you. However, since ECS task definitions are region specific, adding the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable to the task definition should not be a problem.